# find control on page using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm using the FindControl function to look for a control on the page.  It seems super simple and straight forward on MSDN but I can't get it to find the control.  The page I'm using has a MasterPageFile that prepends more to the id that I give the contorl in the aspx file. A simple example that isn't working:

aspx page

```
<%@ Page Title="Inventory Control Test" Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false"     MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.vb"     Inherits="Sales_ajaxTest_Default2" %>

<asp:Content ID="conHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">


</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="conBody" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainBody" Runat="Server">

   <asp:Button ID="saveAllBtn"  runat="server" Text="Save All" /> 

</asp:Content>
```

code behind

```
Partial Class Sales_ajaxTest_Default2
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


Protected Sub saveAllBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles saveAllBtn.Click
    Dim myControl1 As Control = FindControl("ctl00_MainBody_saveAllBtn")
    If (Not myControl1 Is Nothing) Then

        MsgBox("Control ID is : " & myControl1.ID)
    Else
        'Response.Write("Control not found.....")
        MsgBox("Control not found.....")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

I get that msgbox isn't a web thing I'm just using it for this example.
If i use "saveAllBtn", which is the id given to the control, in the FindControl I get "control not found".  If I try this, on a stand alone page without a masterpage it works fine.

If I inspect the element using chrome I find that the ID of the button has been changed to "ctl00_MainBody_saveAllBtn" but if I use that in the FindControl I still get "control not found"

Comment: may be [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/mahesh/archive/2006/06/27/83264.aspx) reading could help.. it is done in c#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use FindControl you would specify the "server ID" (what you named it) of the control, not the final rendered "client ID" of the control. ex:

```
Dim myControl as Control = MainBody.FindControl("saveAllBtn")
```

However, in your specific example, since you are in the `saveAllBtn.Click` event, the control you are looking for is actually the `sender` parameter (because you clicked on that button to trigger the event you are in) ex:

```
Dim myControl as Button = CType(sender, Button)
```

Comment: Yes you're right about sender, that's my fault for using a poor example I should have put another control on the page and attempted to get it by it's ID which would have been more inline with what I'm really trying to do.  If I use MainBody.FindControl visual studio says that MainBody isn't declared. But I can wrap the controls I need in a div with runat server and access it using the same idea. divID.findcontrol works. Thank You

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to find `saveAllBtn` control, wweicker's second method `using CType(sender, Button)` is the prefer one.

However, if you want to find other control by name, you cannot use just `FindControl`. You need to find the control recursively, because it is nested inside other controls.

Here is the helper method -

```
Protected Sub saveAllBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Dim button = TryCast(FindControlRecursive(Me.Page, "saveAllBtn"), Button)
End Sub

Public Shared Function FindControlRecursive(root As Control, id As String) As Control
   If root.ID = id Then
      Return root
   End If

   Return root.Controls.Cast(Of Control)().[Select](Function(c) FindControlRecursive(c, id)).FirstOrDefault(Function(c) c IsNot Nothing)
End Function
```

*Note: My VB code might be a bite weird, because I wrote in C# and converted to VB using [converter](http://converter.telerik.com/).*

Comment: Recursive functions are always fun and I'll try this out.  Thank you for pointing out that I can't just use findcontrol(IdName)

Answer (score 1):

FindControl does not work recursively. You must start at one point (Me, for example), and if that is not the control your looking for, search the Controls collection of your starting point. And so forth.