# How can I control my textboxes' display using Me.Controls in Vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have about four or more textboxes on my screen but I set false to visible.
As the result (count) of my database table, I want to show the textboxes.
Here is my code.

```
//my datatable list
Dim dl As List(Of String) = dt.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Select(Function(dr) dr(0).ToString).ToList
For i As Integer = 1 To dl.Count
            Me.Controls("txtSrc" & i.ToString).Visible = True
Next
```

Then, I have this kind of error .

```
InvalidCastException: String The conversion from "lblSrc1" to type'Integer' is invalid.
```

How can I fix that error?

Note; I am using VS 2019<<ASP.NET webform (using VB.NET)>>

Comment: based on your current syntax, you're probably looking for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find control on page using vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453831/find-control-on-page-using-vb-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I am sorry that I forgot to say I have a Master page.
So I tried that way and it did work for me. Thanks.

```
 For i As Integer = 1 To dl.Count
            Dim mpContentPlaceHolder As ContentPlaceHolder = CType(Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1"), ContentPlaceHolder)            
            Dim txt As TextBox = CType(mpContentPlaceHolder.FindControl("TextBox" & i), TextBox)
            txt.Visible = True
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, unlike say VBA/VB6 - maybe vb.net desktop?

You get getting a type conversion error because

```
    Me.Controls()
```

Wants a number (index value) into the controls collection.

So, you can't use a string or "variable" to reference the controls the same way you can say in VBA/Access/VB6

So, your example code would become this:

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count
        Dim Tbox As TextBox
        Tbox = Me.FindControl("TextBox" & i)
        Tbox.Visible = False
    Next
```

Also, there is little (no reason) to convert the data table into a list to get the row count, since a data table as above shows .Rows.Count is the same value

So

```
 Dim dl As List(Of String) = dt.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Select(Function(dr) dr(0).ToString).ToList

dim MyRowCount1 as integer = dl.Count
dim MyRowCount2 as integer = dt.Rows.Count
```

BOTH above will result in the SAME row count value - so you can dump that messy first line of code to convert the dt to a list. Not required.
(so, with above both RowCount1 and RowCount2 would have same value and same result)

So this should do the trick:

```
   For i As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count
        Dim Tbox As TextBox
        Tbox = Me.FindControl("TextBox" & i)
        Tbox.Visible = False
    Next
```

Comment: Thz you again. Actually I did 'Tbox = Me.FindControl("TextBox" & i)' before. But I got Nothing in Tbox.

Comment: all good - if it is working - then mark as answer - and good luck on your project.

Comment: It still didn't work , I got Nothing as the result of Tbox. Thz you.

Comment: Hum, perhaps post the markup of the text boxes you have. My example assumes TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3. So post your markup - as what I named my text box controls may well be different than what you have.